# RXJS: How to reset the values of a BehaviorSubject Array

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this Behaviorsubject:

```
_list: BehaviorSubject<BehaviorSubject<object>[]>; 
 list: Observable<Observable<object>[]>;
//That I create like this in the constructor: 
 this._list= new BehaviorSubject<BehaviorSubject<object>[]>([]);
 this.list= this._messages.asObservable();
```

Now at some point I want to reset _list without disconnecting Subscribers. 
My first attempt was:

```
this._list.next([]);
```

But this approach yields this Error:

```
Error: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. 
You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

Another approach was to call this again:

```
this._list= new BehaviorSubject<BehaviorSubject<object>[]>([]);
this.list= this._messages.asObservable();
```

Buth this approach disconnects every subscriber.

How can I give list an empty BehaviorSubject Array?

**EDIT**

Full Error Stack as requested:

```
Error: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at subscribeTo (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:236751:15)
    at subscribeToResult (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:236890:76)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:232103:90)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:232097:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:232080:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:227382:18)
    at BehaviorSubject.next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:227168:25)
    at BehaviorSubject.next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:226649:15)
    at MsgControllerService.renewMessages (http://localhost:4200/main.js:3279:24)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.js:2880:40
(anonymous) @ chat-manager.service.ts:55
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:359
onInvoke @ core.js:39698
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:358
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
(anonymous) @ zone-evergreen.js:855
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:391
onInvokeTask @ core.js:39679
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:390
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:559
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:469
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1603
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone-evergreen.js:1629
```

Relevant Code for the Error:

```
addMessages(messages: object[]): void {
    if (messages.length > 0) {
      let newMessages = messages.map(message => {
        message['visualisationState'] = MsgControllerService.initVisualisationState();
        message['visualisationState'].strongLabels = MsgControllerService.getTopLabels(message, this.numberOfTopLabels);
        return new BehaviorSubject<object>(message);
      });
      this.addMessageToMessages(newMessages);
    }
  }

  renewMessages(messages: object[]) {
    this._messages.next([]);
    this.addMessages(messages);
  }
  addMessageToMessages(newMessage: BehaviorSubject<object>[]) {
    this._messages.next(this._messages.getValue().concat(newMessage)); // Error thrown here
  }
```

Comment: The error you mention with `this._list.next([]);` weird. This should never throw such error.

Comment: Where in your code is this error thrown? The error message should tell you the file and line. Post this part of your code here.

Comment: Edited Question with the requested info.

Answer (score 4):

Why you are creating BehaviorSubject inside BehaviorSubject? Just do this:

```
    _list: BehaviorSubject<any[]>; 
    list: Observable<any[]>;
    //That I create like this in the constructor: 
    this._list= new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
    this.list= this._messages.asObservable();
```

Comment: Because I listen to the each element of the list of course.

Comment: making a subject of subject is unnecessary, just use combination operator or simple array of subject.
@CoveredEe 's response is the way

Comment: You can listen to a complete array with just one BehaviorSubject, then subscribe to it and do whatever you want inside the component with every single element(maybe using map operator inside the pipe etc). Remember there is more than 100 operator to work with Observable stream.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that any pipe() on list (messages if you read the error Details) will always execute, even in conditionals. My code had this method:

```
if (index < this.msgController.getLengthOfMessages()) {
      return this.msgController.messages.pipe(mergeMap(messages => {
        let message = messages.reverse()[index];
        messages.reverse();
        return message;
      }));
    } else {
      return null;
    }
```

Meaning that even though I checked that the messages/list have values, .pipe() will still execute, with an empty array. 
The simple solution to this would be to guarantee to return a valid Observable which I did like this:

```
if(!message) return messages;
```

since the method does not return the result of the pipe this doesnt pose an issue in my case.